# Get the name of a Glassfish2 domain

Tags: java, glassfish, jmx, esb, jcaps

is it possible to get the name of the current domain in Glassfish v2?

I've got a code like:

```
    MemoryMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
    if (bean != null) {
        MemoryUsage usage = bean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage();
        int current = (int) ((double) usage.getUsed() / usage.getMax() * 100);
        ch.log( Level.INFO, "Memory usage : (non heap) " + usage + " -- "+current+"% (limit:"+THRESHOLD+"%)");
        if (current > THRESHOLD) {
            //send email
        }
```

which would send us an email when the appserver is about to crash (PermGen space exception); but we've got 3 appserver running, so the domain name would be really usefull ... any idea?

Thanks

Comment: AMX can be used from 'inside the appserver'.  It is the primary API used by the Admin Console/GUI to collect and edit configuration data.

Comment: It is a chicken and egg that is solved in the Admin Console... maybe you should open a new question related to that aspect of the problem.

Comment: +1 for the simple fact that you also share in the pain known as JCAPS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
MBeanServerConnection serv;
if (hostname != null) {
    //remote connection
    JMXServiceURL u = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + hostname + "/jmxrmi");
    String[] credentials = new String[]{"admin", "adminadmin"};
    Map<String, String[]> environment = new LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>();
    environment.put("jmx.remote.credentials", credentials);

    JMXConnector c = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(u, environment);
    serv = c.getMBeanServerConnection();
} else {
    //local connection
    serv = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
}

//connect to AMX
DomainRoot dRoot = ProxyFactory.getInstance(serv).getDomainRoot(true) ;

//get the Administrative domain name in the Domain Configuration
Map<String, String> map = dRoot.getDomainConfig().getProperties() ;
System.out.println(map.get("administrative.domain.name"));
```

with `hostname` equals to `"host:port"`, or `null` if you want to connect the the local JVM

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AMX](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/amx/index.html) to get the domain name.  It is a available from [DomainRoot](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/nonav/javaee5/amx/javadoc/com/sun/appserv/management/DomainRoot.html).getAppserverDomainName().

Comment: there is an example at http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4336/beapq?l=en&a=view ; but it seems that DomainRoot is meant to be used from outside of the appserver (RMI connection) ... and in my JCAPS environment, I would think that I can't use appserver-specific libraries ... Thank you anyway

Comment: yes, you're certainly right, but how can I know the port number I'm supposed to connect to? it's the chicken and the egg! :)

Answer (score 1):

it's not the most beautifull solution, but this hack works:

```
String dirName = (new File( ".." )).getCanonicalPath();
int dirNameIdx = dirName.lastIndexOf( File.separator );
if (dirNameIdx != -1) 
    APPSERVER = dirName.substring( dirNameIdx + 1 );
    ch.log( Level.INFO, "Memory usage: Appserver name: " + APPSERVER );
}
```

provided that the working directory is .../domains/domain/config

Answer (score 0):

Building on Kevin's answer, if you just want to use JMX (without relying on AMX libraries) just by using the getPropertyValue method on the J2EEDomain mbean.

```
MBeanServerConnection serv;

//remote connection
JMXServiceURL u = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + hostname + "/jmxrmi");
String[] credentials = new String[]{"admin", "adminadmin"};
Map<String, String[]> environment = new LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>();
environment.put("jmx.remote.credentials", credentials);

JMXConnector c = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(u, environment);
serv = c.getMBeanServerConnection();
String domainName = (String) mbsc.invoke(new ObjectName("com.sun.appserv:j2eeType=J2EEDomain,name=com.sun.appserv,category=runtime"), "getPropertyValue", new String[] {"administrative.domain.name"}, new Object[] {"java.lang.String"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple way that we've been using

```
db.getHISTORICAL_MEMORY_USAGE().setDOMAIN( System.getProperty( "domain.name" ) );
db.getHISTORICAL_MEMORY_USAGE().setSERVER( System.getProperty( "com.sun.aas.hostName" ) );
```

Comment: where do you get this `db` object, what's its class?

Comment: db object was our oracle table otd. System.getProperty works on windows and aix for us in production